# lml-list-item `padding-left` do not work?

Tags: html, css, cordova

In my project, my item's `padding-left` is set by previous `stylesheet`

And we can see there is `padding-left` 15px:

If I uncheck the `padding-left`:

Uncheck the `padding-left` is my requirement, so I write a `css`:

```
.lml-list-item  {
    background-color:#111111;
    padding-left:0px;  // I set padding-left:0px;

}
```

Then I check the html in the `firefox`, but found my `css` did not use:

Why my `css` do not work? and no matter I set `lml-list-item`  in front or after the class, it always not work.

```
<a href="#" class="lml-list-item item-link item-content ">
    <li class="item-content lml-item-content">
        <div class="item-media black"><i class="icon icon-f7"></i></div>
        <div class="item-inner">
             <div class="item-title">info</div>
         </div>
    </li>
 </a>
```

Comment: can i see the css for that html line? what is list block, where it should be?

Comment: Sounds like a) your stylesheet isn't included/updated. b) there's not enough specificity to override the css. You could always smash in the frowned upon `!important` tag ;)

Comment: add "display:inline-block" to ".lml-list-item "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your `15px padding` impacts deeper than just `.lml-list-item` Try:

```
.list-block>ul>.item-content.lml-list-item {
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

Or as last alternative an `!important` override:

```
.lml-list-item {
   padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the pictures you've included, the `padding-left: 15px` is set on `.list-block .item-content`, so assigning a rule for `.lml-list-item` will of course not work.

Using `.list-block .item-content.lml-list-item` will, and perhaps also `.list-block .lml-list-item` as long as it's included after the existing stylesheet. Also, if you want to override just a few rules, you could just add a `<style>`-block to `<head>` in the actual file (instead of adding another stylesheet), as inline / declared styles will override stylesheet-styels.